# Responsive Multi Images with Scrolling

Tags: html, css

I wanna try something in django but i couldnt find any solution.
Firstly i made this page
In this picture, you will see 8 pictures (everything is ok for me, no problem)
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PyzC.jpg)

But Second picture i have a two problem
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNvvZ.jpg)

When you look at the picture you will see 8 images in mobile screen. I dont want to show all images in mobile screen, i want to show 2 or 3 images and if you want to see other images you can slide with your finger or any good idea.

How can i do this.

These are my codes...

```html
{% load static %}
{% include 'base.html' %}

<style type="text/css">

.container {
    width: 90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align:center;
    
}

.box {
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    background: gray;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.box img {border-radius: 6px;}

.box:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    background: black;
    z-index: 2;
}

body {
    background-color:white; 

    }

</style>


    <div class="container" >
    <div class="box"><img src="{% static 'images/128.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" ></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="{% static 'images/128.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" ></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="{% static 'images/128.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" ></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="{% static 'images/128.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" ></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="{% static 'images/128.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" ></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="{% static 'images/128.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" ></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="{% static 'images/128.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" ></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="{% static 'images/128.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you don't want to display the images squashed then you have to remove Flex

Comment: i removed all flex codes, but this time all images listed top to bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of all, remove all the `flexbox` items.

If you give the class `.box` `display: inline-block;` then the `.box`  takes only the width of the image. Then you have to give the `.container` an `overflow: auto;` to scroll and `white-space: nowrap;` so that they are displayed side by side.

Change the width of the container if you want.

Here is the finished code:

```html
{% load static %}
{% include 'base.html' %}

<style type="text/css">


/* Hiding Scrollbar */

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.container {
  -ms-overflow-style: none; 
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

/* Hiding Scrollbar end */

.container {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0 20px 0;
    text-align:center;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.box {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    background: gray;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    display: inline-block;
}

.box img {border-radius: 6px;}

.box:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    background: black;
    z-index: 2;
}

body {
    background-color:white; 

    }

</style>


    <div class="container" >
    <div class="box"><img src="{% static 'images/128.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" ></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="{% static 'images/128.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" ></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="{% static 'images/128.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" ></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="{% static 'images/128.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" ></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="{% static 'images/128.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" ></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="{% static 'images/128.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" ></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="{% static 'images/128.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" ></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="{% static 'images/128.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, you solved my problem. Really really thank you very much. I wanna ask last question, when i looked mobile screen, i see scrool bar, is there any way to make hidden?